# CakePHP 3 on view show the field from a belongTo association model

Tags: php, cakephp, associations, cakephp-3.0

Lets say that i have the following associations schema:

```
Person => [
     hasMany => [
         Courses => [Person.id = Courses.person_id]
     ],
Courses => [
    belongTo => [
         Schools => [School.id = Courses.school_id]
    ]
```

When I view a person through `mydomain/person/view/1` I need to have a table to show the Courses of that Person. Inside this table each Course need to show the name of the School.

So I tried the following on my controller:

```
public function view($id = null)
{
    $person = $this->Persons->get($id, [
        'contain' => [
            'Courses.Schools',
        ]
    ]);
    $this->set('persons', $test);
    $this->set('_serialize', ['person']);
}
```

What I get on view is:

```
Person => [
    firstname => test,
    lastname => test,
    courses => [
        0 => [
            id => 1,
            shool_id => 1,
            person_id => 1,
        ]
    ]
]
```

There is no school in the array although I used it in the contain option. So I can't display the name of the school. Am I doing anything wrong? Is there any guideline how can I show these fields on the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically I am sorry for this. This is a caused because of the `debugKit`. The `debugkit` is showing through the variables panel the associations only until the level I have mentioned but I used a `var_dump` and saw that the associations and the related fields are fetched/loaded correctly. I trusted the debugKit and I thought that they where not loaded.